# ReactJS - Problem of URL when redirect page in mode build

Tags: reactjs, redirect, webpack, build, wamp

I'm new in react.
I deploy a react-app in wamp server with npm run-script build 
the location is  : http://localhost/react-app

My login URL is : http://localhost/react-app/#/login

After login , I redirect the page to the '/'
this is the code :

```html
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
```

The URL becomes to : http://localhost/#/
But I want to have http://localhost/react-app/#/

What is the best way to do this ? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/react-app', state: { from: props.location } }} /> ?

Comment: for this, it's becomes to : http://localhost/react-app/#/react-app/

Answer (score 0):

ALFA.
You can code your project like this:

```
var projectName = "react-app"
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/${projectName}/`, state: { from: props.location } }} />
</Router>
```

And if you need to change the projectName will be easy do that using this pattern.
I used something we call Template strings or Template literals, [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

By the way, I usually create api folder, that has all important backend configurations to use as a sample at any time.

```
import api './../somefolder'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/${projectName}/`, state: { from: props.location } }} />
</Router>
```

Can you try this and check if its works ?

Comment: Thanks but the url becomes to http://localhost/#/react-app , I want to have http://localhost/react-app/#/